# Text overflow not working for extra lines

Tags: flutter

Text.overflow doesn't apply on new lines :

```
Text(text,
     maxLines: 3,
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
```

with 3 lines with the last being too long, overflow is working, but with 4 lines, the first 3 are displayed and no ellipsis is present :

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

result will be

```
line1
line2
line3
```

No ellipsis added, I was expecting

```
line1
line2
line3...
```

or

```
line1
line2
line3
...
```

Any way to do that ? I would prefer to keep the breaklines.

Comment: Maybe linked to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761

Answer (score 1):

what you need is [expandable_text](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_text):

```
ExpandableText(
        longText,
        expandText: '...',
        collapseText: '',
        maxLines: 3,
        linkColor: Colors.black,
    );
```

Comment: This library is indeed interesting, but doesn't do exactly what I wanted. I guess I would need to build a custom widget, inspired by this library to truncate to 3 lines and apply an ellipsis at the end. (like what they did with the "show more" link)

Answer (score 0):

if your text contain **breaklines** or '\n'
then it **is not recognized as overflow**.
ellipsis will not appear if text doesn't overflow the width of the parent before interfering with breakline

try this and it will work

```
Text(" Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book , ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book , ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.",
     maxLines: 3,
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a solution that let's me keep the breaklines.